# Accesing optional fields in the Credit Card Object

Tags: balanced-payments

I am using Balanced version 1.0 on PHP.

We have tried to add more details to the Credit Cards.  The ones we are having problems with are, from the documentation these are listed as;

- city    optional string. City. Defaults to null.
- state   optional string. US state. This field has been deprecated.

When I examine the $card object, these properties do not exist, except as part of the customer sub-object.  The other properties;

- postal_code
- street_address
- country_code

operate as expected.

While **state** is termed "deprecated", this means that is may be superseded not removed. **city** is should default to null but is not there. I examined v1.1 and see that the fields are still there as part of the sub-object address.

Can you suggest why I cannot access these fields in v1.0?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at [the documentation](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.0/api/cards/#retrieve-a-card) and it shows those fields come back on the response.

Can you expand on what you mean by them not existing? Are you attempting to set them and the values do not persist?

#### Request

```
curl https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP2zmzeddBrHjK5zoThHGpzi/cards/CC3Mb8s5fGvC49F8mWteu8Mm \
     -u ak-test-2755A6Q56FwdnGMNXK72fHjCSXXlruJe6:
```

#### Response

```
{
    "_type": "card", 
    "_uris": {}, 
    "account": null, 
    "brand": "MasterCard", 
    "card_type": "mastercard", 
    "country_code": null, 
    "created_at": "2014-03-31T21:21:55.367725Z", 
    "customer": null, 
    "expiration_month": 12, 
    "expiration_year": 2020, 
    "hash": "fc4ccd5de54f42a5e75f76fbfde60948440c7a382ee7d21b2bc509ab9cfed788", 
    "id": "CC3Mb8s5fGvC49F8mWteu8Mm", 
    "is_valid": true, 
    "is_verified": true, 
    "last_four": "5100", 
    "meta": {}, 
    "name": null, 
    "postal_code": null, 
    "postal_code_check": "unknown", 
    "security_code_check": "passed", 
    "street_address": null, 
    "uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP2zmzeddBrHjK5zoThHGpzi/cards/CC3Mb8s5fGvC49F8mWteu8Mm"
}
```

If you look at the response you can see that the fields `postal_code`, `street_address`, and `country_code` all exist in the payload.

If you think it's something related to the PHP client itself then the best bet is to generate a runnable example that we can use to debug the issue. You can either post it here or [create an issue on the github repo for the Balanced PHP client](http://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. postal_code, street_address, country_code
operate as expected.  The fields city and state are the ones that are missing although they are documented.  https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.0/api/cards/#tokenize-a-card.
Yes I attempting to set them and the values, which do not persist.